# Parsing for data in HTML using XPath (in a shell script)

Tags: html, xml, parsing, shell, xpath

I am trying to parse a fairly simple web page for information in a shell script. The web page I'm working with now is generated [here](http://aruljohn.com/details.php). For example, I would like to pull the information on the internet service provider into a shell variable. It may make sense to use one of the programs xmllint, XMLStarlet or xpath for this purpose. I am quite familiar with shell scripting, but I am new to XPath syntax and the utilities used to implement the XPath syntax, so I would appreciate a few pointers in the right direction.

Here's the beginnings of the shell script:

```
HTMLISPInformation="$(curl --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0" http://aruljohn.com/details.php)"
# ISP="$(<XPath magic goes here.>)"
```

For your convenience, here is a utility for dynamically testing XPath syntax online:

http://www.bit-101.com/xpath/

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

Answer (score 9):

Quick and dirty solution...

```
xmllint --html -xpath "//table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]" page.html
```

You can find the xpath of your node using Chrome and the Developer Tools. When inspecting the node, right click on it and select copy XPath.

I wouldn't use this too much, this is not very reliable.

All the information on your page can be found elsewhere: run whois on your own IP for instance...

Comment: I get "XPath set is empty", even [piping through `sed -e 's/xmlns=".*"//g'``](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264134/xmllint-failing-to-properly-query-with-xpath)

Comment: I had some success with specifying full path from root /html/body/table/tr/td ... and also removing the <!DOCTYPE directive.

Answer (score 5):

You could use my  [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html). Extracting values from html pages in the cli is its main purpose. Although it is not a standard tool, it is a single, dependency-free binary, and can be installed/run without being root.

It can directly read the value from the webpage without involving other programs.

With XPath:

```
 xidel http://aruljohn.com/details.php -e '//td[text()="Internet Provider"]/following-sibling::td'
```

Or with pattern-matching:

```
 xidel http://aruljohn.com/details.php -e '<td>Internet Provider</td><td>{.}</td>' --hide-variable-names
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider on using [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/). It is a headless WebKit, which allows you to execute JavaScript/CoffeeScript on a web page. I think it could help you solve your issue.

[Pjscrape](http://nrabinowitz.github.com/pjscrape/) is a useful web scraping tool based on PhantomJs.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at it for my personal use. However, the task I hope to accomplish is to be done on a server on which I am not granted root access, which is why I mentioned standard tools such as xmllint.

Comment: Do you need root access? You could just copy it in your user folder and run it from there.

Answer (score 3):

### [`xpup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/xpup)

#### XML

A command line XML parsing tool written in Go. For example:

```
$ curl -sL https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml | xpup '/*/body'
Don't forget me this weekend!
```

or:

```
$ xpup '/note/from' < <(curl -sL https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml)
Jani
```

#### HTML

Here is the example of parsing HTML page:

```
$ xpup '/*/head/title' < <(curl -sL https://example.com/)
Example Domain
```

---

### [`pup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup)

For HTML parsing, try [`pup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup). For example:

```
$ pup 'title text{}' -f <(curl -sL https://example.com/)
Example Domain
```

See related [Feature Request for XPath](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup/issues/35).

#### Installation

Install by: `go get github.com/ericchiang/pup`.

Answer (score 1):

#### HTML-XML-utils

There are many command-line tools in [HTML-XML-utils](http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/README) package which can parse HTML files (e.g. `hxselect` to match a CSS selector).

Also there is `xpath` which is command-line wrapper around Perl's XPath library (`XML::Path`).

Related: [Command line tool to query HTML elements](https://superuser.com/q/507344/87805) at SU