# xmllint give attribute only if elements are present unix

Tags: xml, unix, xpath, filter, xmllint

I have an XML as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:myproject>
<tns:site name="London"/>
<tns:site name="Paris"/>
<tns:site name="New York"/>

<tns:node hostname="S1" IP="10.10.10.1" siteid="London">
        <tns:elements>
        <tns:database/>
    </tns:elements>
</tns:node>
<tns:node hostname="S1" IP="10.10.10.2" siteid="London">
    <tns:elements>
        <tns:admin/>
    </tns:elements>
</tns:node>

<tns:node hostname="S2" IP="10.10.10.3" siteid="Paris">
        <tns:elements>
        <tns:database/>
    </tns:elements>
</tns:node>
<tns:node hostname="S2" IP="10.10.10.4" siteid="Paris">
    <tns:elements>
        <tns:admin/>
    </tns:elements>
</tns:node>

<tns:node hostname="S3" IP="10.10.10.5" siteid="New York">
        <tns:elements>
        <tns:database/>
    </tns:elements>
</tns:node>
<tns:node hostname="S3" IP="10.10.10.6" siteid="New York">
    <tns:elements>
        <tns:admin/>
    </tns:elements>
</tns:node>
</tns:myproject>
```

I need the values hostname, IP and siteid if the element `database` is present in `node`.

Expected output:

```
hostname="S1" IP="10.10.10.1" siteid="London"
hostname="S2" IP="10.10.10.2" siteid="Paris"
hostname="S3" IP="10.10.10.3" siteid="New York"
```

I am new to xmllint, so I tried few commands in unix like

`xpath project.xml "//@hostname"` or `echo 'cat //@hostname' | xmllint --shell "topo.p.xml"`

But don't know how can I filter it based on tag `database`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can use xpath predicate (`[]`) to filter element. *Assume* that your XML *doesn't have namespace prefix* involved, the following xpath will get `hostname` attribute from `<node>` element having descendant element `<database>`:

```
//node[elements/database]/@hostname
```

Since your actual XML *has prefix* involved you need to declare namespace prefix first, probably [using `stns`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264134/xmllint-failing-to-properly-query-with-xpath) command (I'm not xmllint user)  :

```
xmllint --shell project.xml
stns tns=uri.for.tns.here.according.to.your.xml
```

Then use the registered prefix in your xpath :

```
//tns:node[tns:elements/tns:database]/@hostname
```