# Getting xmllint property with xmlns in bash

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, xmllint

There is the following config.xml file (the file is from a source repository what I cannot change in an automated process; I can change the build process though so ideas on how to extract two properties, the androidversionCode and the iosCFBundleVersion would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.company.project" version="1.2.8" androidversionCode="209" iosCFBundleVersion="209" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Project name</name>
    <description>Project description</description>
</widget>
```

What I try:

```
$ xmllint --xpath "string(//widget/@id)" config.xml
```

That only works when xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" is removed from the file.  If I set xmlns="" then it works too, but I found no other cases it would be returning id or any version code.  So, xmlns="something" makes xpath fail, right?

How can I make this work and fetch those version numbers?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264134/xmllint-failing-to-properly-query-with-xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the resolution is:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//*[local-name()="widget"]/@id)' config.xml
```