# Why this xpath doesn't work?

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

given docuent a.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <listUsersResponse xmlns="http://www.algorithmics.com/schema">
    <status>OK</status>
    <users size="615">
      <user>
        <id>user1</id>
        <name>Joe Doe</name>
        <attributes size="0"/>
        <status>ACTIVE</status>
        <roleId>CREDIT_SUPPORT</roleId>
        <password>454E454A77484D3566717547686858726842503755513D3D</password>
        <timeout>0</timeout>
      </user>
      <user>
        <id>user2</id>
        <name>Tom Smith</name>
        <attributes size="0"/>
        <status>ACTIVE</status>
        <roleId>RISK_MANAGEMENT</roleId>
        <password>627678416458513567624E37384C314E626C30672B773D3D</password>
        <timeout>0</timeout>
      </user>
    </users>
  </listUsersResponse>
</xml>
```

I want to extract the xml of the `<user>` node which has a id element with value "user1".

**@skovorodkin**: thank you for the tip. now I get the node. but it doesn't show the full contents of the node:

```
$  xmllint --shell a.xml <<EOF
...setns x=http://www.algorithmics.com/schema
...xpath //x:users/x:user[x:id="user1"]
...EOF
/ > / > Object is a Node Set :
Set contains 1 nodes:
1  ELEMENT user
```

I expect:

```
<user>
        <id>user1</id>
        <name>Joe Doe</name>
        <attributes size="0"/>
        <status>ACTIVE</status>
        <roleId>CREDIT_SUPPORT</roleId>
        <password>454E454A77484D3566717547686858726842503755513D3D</password>
        <timeout>0</timeout>
 </user>
```

Comment: Your XML has a namespace, so you have to adjust your query. Check out this answer for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8266075/847552

Comment: Thanks. I updated my post. would it be possible to display the full content of the result?

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the answer on the other question if it helped. ;-)

Comment: I got the solution: use cat //x:users/x:user[x:id="user1"] instead.

Answer (score 2):

The XPath is working correctly and selecting the element you are looking for. You have an issue displaying the node that the XPath expression found. That's going to depend on the application or tool that you use to process the results of the XPath, not on the XPath itself.