# xmllint not returning what I expect -- n00b warning

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, xmllint

The Problem>  I have some xml returned from an API call stored in get_build_info.xml.  I am trying to grab an attribute from that xml, build_id.  Here is the xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<buildinfo xmlns:xsi="http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;www.w3.org&#x2f;2001&#x2f;XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;analysiscenter.veracode.com&#x2f;schema&#x2f;4.0&#x2f;buildinfo" xsi:schemaLocation="https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;analysiscenter.veracode.com&#x2f;schema&#x2f;4.0&#x2f;buildinfo https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;analysiscenter.veracode.com&#x2f;resource&#x2f;4.0&#x2f;buildinfo.xsd" buildinfo_version="1.4" account_id="1234" app_id="010101" sandbox_id="020202" build_id="987654321"><build version="4 Sep 2020 Static &#x28;2&#x29;" build_id="987654321" submitter="Someone Else" platform="Not Specified" lifecycle_stage="Not Specified" results_ready="true" policy_name="Some Development App Policy" policy_version="7" policy_compliance_status="Conditional Pass" rules_status="Not Assessed" grace_period_expired="false" scan_overdue="false" legacy_scan_engine="false">
      <analysis_unit analysis_type="Static" published_date="2020-09-04T11&#x3a;44&#x3a;09-04&#x3a;00" published_date_sec="1599234249" status="Results Ready" engine_version="20200821190810"/>
   </build>
</buildinfo>
```

What I've tried> The following, and many other variations thereof:

`xmllint --xpath 'string(//xml/buildinfo/@build_id)' get_build_info.xml`

`xmllint --xpath 'string(//buildinfo/@build_id)' get_build_info.xml`

`xmllint --xpath 'string(/xml/buildinfo/@build_id)' get_build_info.xml`

`xmllint --xpath '(//xml/buildinfo/build_id/text())' get_build_info.xml`

`xmllint --xpath '(/xml/buildinfo/build_id/text())' get_build_info.xml`

The last two at least yield some kind of output, albeit be that "XPath set is empty".  The first few where I'm using that 'string( +...+ @build_id in the --xpath, I just get nothing returned.  These all appear to exit 0 from bash as well so there's no syntax issue from what I can tell.  Like I said, I'm a n00b.  I looked at other popular tickets on stackoverflow and that's what got me to this point.  I might very well not be taking something obvious into account here, so assume that I know nothing about bash (which is close to true).  I'm happy to be given a direction to go and find the answer myself.

Comment: It is about the namespace, this is a useful read with solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264134/xmllint-failing-to-properly-query-with-xpath/8266075#8266075

Comment: Thank you!  I'm checking the link out now, seems exactly what my issue is and what I need to read up on.

Comment: If you're interested in an alternative, like [tag:xidel], you can do just: `xidel -s get_build_info.xml -e '//@build_id'`.

Comment: Will check that out too.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're are getting entangled with namespaces, so try using an xpath expression like:

```
//*[local-name()='buildinfo']/@build_id
```

and see if it works.

Comment: !!  This returned the value I needed and a little bit extra -```build_id="987654321"``` .  That's fantastic progress.  I'm assuming there is some nifty way to pull the actual value out of that as well.  Will be looking into that, any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: @new2tech It should not do that - but try putting `string()` around the whole thing. Also - more generally, consider using something like xmlstarlet, or - more advanced - xidel.

Comment: string() around the whole --xpath expression?  I've tried a few different options but I think I'm not getting the right spot in the xpath for this:

```xmllint --xpath string("//*[local-name()='buildinfo']/@build_id")```

```xmllint --xpath "string(//*[local-name()='buildinfo']/@build_id)"```

Due to limitiations with which dependencies can be installed, xmllint may be the only tool for this situation, but I will look into the other suggestions.  Thanks you!

Comment: Oh wait - I got it!  it was 

```xmllint --xpath "string(//*[local-name()='buildinfo']/@build_id)" get_build_info.xml```

That looks like the exact same command (#2) that I listed in my above comment.. not sure what I did wrong but It's there and assigned to a variable!! Thank you!

Comment: Turns out there were some weird syntax errors when I tabbed-completed the get_build_info.xml.  That was my problem.

Comment: Done.  Apparently I can't upvote your answer, but it is now the solution :)