# Extract XML with xmllint --xpath

Tags: linux, xml, bash, xmllint

I am having trouble extracting the `"EXTRACT_THIS_PLEASE"` from a similar XML file using `xmllint --xpath`. I understand sed and awk should not be used from some Googling. I also see that other XML parsers are usually recommended, but this is the only one I seem to have on my RHEL system. I have tried various things and understand that the issue has to do with white spaces.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <model-response-list xmlns="http://www.website.com/thing/link/linktothing/linklink" total-models="1" throttle="1" error="EndOfResults">
        <model-responses>
            <model mh="0x12345678">
                <attribute id="0x12345">EXTRACT_THIS_PLEASE</attribute>
            </model>
        </model-responses>
    </model-response-list>
```

EDIT: kjhughes and j_b, you guys are both wizards. Thank you so much. Could I also also extract 0x12345678 from "". I am looking to do this 5000+ times and ultimately have a list of devices in rows or columns like this:

```
"0x12345678
EXTRACT_THIS_PLEASE
0x99999999
EXTRACT_THIS_PLEASE
0x11111111
NOTHING
0x33333333
EXTRACT_THIS_PLEASE
0x22222222
NOTHING"
```

Answer (score 2):

This xmllint command line,

```
xmllint --xpath "//*[@id='0x12345']/text()" file.xml
```

will select

```
EXTRACT_THIS_PLEASE
```

as requested.

### See also

- [Daniel Haley's answer showing how to use XML namespaces in xmllint.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8266075/290085)

Comment: kjhughes and j_b, you guys are both wizards. Thank you so much. Could I also also extract 0x12345678 from "<model mh="0x12345678">". I am looking to do this 5000+ times and ultimately have a list of devices in rows or columns like this:

    0x12345678
    EXTRACT_THIS_PLEASE
0x99999999
EXTRACT_THIS_PLEASE
0x11111111
NOTHING
EXTRACT_THIS_PLEASE
0x22222222
NOTHING

Comment: @Musik847 per your follow-up question, you may wish to have a look into XSLT transform to produce the output you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to extract the contents of the `<attribute>` elemenet:

```
xmllint --xpath "//*[name()='attribute']/text()" x.xml
```

Output:

```
EXTRACT_THIS_PLEASE
```