# Need to read data from xml using xmllint

Tags: xml, xmllint

I would like to read "url-pattern" from below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>APP Services</display-name>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginLogoutMapping</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name >APP restricted URLs</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/services.jsp</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/Debug.jsp</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/encode.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Tried some commands. Doesn't help/

sh-4.4$ xmllint --xpath '//web-app/security-constraint/web-resource-collection/web-resource-name/' /optconf/web.xml
XPath error : Invalid expression
XPath evaluation failure
sh-4.4$
sh-4.4$

Comment: The xpath in the error ends with a `/`. You also don’t have `url-pattern` in the path. Thirdly, your xml has a default namespace which you’ll need to account for. (This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8266075/317052)

Comment: Tried below.

sh-4.4$ xmllint --xpath '//web-app/security-constraint/web-resource-collection/web-resource-name/url-pattern/text()' /opt/conf/web.xml
XPath set is empty
sh-4.4$ 

Seems, I am missing something.

Comment: Even I am not able to read the web-resource-name

```sh-4.4$ 
sh-4.4$ xmllint --xpath '//web-app/security-constraint/web-resource-collection/web-resource-name/text()' /opt/conf/web.xml
XPath set is empty
sh-4.4$ ```

Comment: Even though hyphens are allowed in element names, yet many parsers treat special characters in element names differently.

Comment: @Blue - because of the default namespace (`xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"`)

Comment: Thank you pmf, Daniel

Is there any other way to read the url-pattern ?

Comment: @Blue - I added an answer that uses one of the examples in the answer I linked to above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appears to be caused by the xpath ending in a `/`.

You also don’t have `url-pattern` in the path.

Thirdly, your xml has a default namespace which you’ll need to account for. ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8266075/317052) should help.)

Here's an example using the `local-name()` option from the answer linked above:

```
==> xmllint --xpath '/*[local-name()="web-app"]/*[local-name()="security-constraint"]/*[local-name()="web-resource-collection"]/*[local-name()="url-pattern"]' input.xml 
<url-pattern>/services.jsp</url-pattern><url-pattern>/Debug.jsp</url-pattern><url-pattern>/encode.jsp</url-pattern>
```

This will select the three `url-pattern` elements that are descendants of security constraint. (This xpath can probably be simplified if some requirements on which `url-pattern` elements need to be selected.)

Also, newer versions of xmlstarlet (I used 1.6.1) allow `_` as a namespace prefix that will match nodes in any namespace. It also gives you greater control over the output.

Example...

```
==> xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/_:web-app/_:security-constraint/_:web-resource-collection' -v '_:url-pattern' input.xml 
/services.jsp
/Debug.jsp
/encode.jsp
```

Comment: Hello Daniel,

Thank you. XMLLINT one working as expected.

```
xmllint --xpath '/*[local-name()="web-app"]/*[local-name()="security-constraint"]/*[local-name()="web-resource-collection"]/*[local-name()="url-pattern"]' input.xml 
```